# print string got by C getchar function

Tags: c

I was testing one of simple getchar() function on GNU compiler, but why not get expected output

```
mto@ubuntu:~/c$ ./a.out 
agc

mto@ubuntu:~/c$
```

code as following :

```
#include <string.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#define MAX 80
int main()
  {
        char  ch, buffer[MAX+1];
        int x=0 ;
        while ((ch =getchar() != '\n') && x<MAX)
                buffer[x++]= ch;
         buffer[x]= '\0';

 int len = strlen(buffer);

for (int c=0; c< len; c++)
       printf("%c" , buffer[c]);
       return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please format your code consistently before asking people to look at it.

Comment: This `(ch = getchar() != '\n')` should be `(ch = getchar()) != '\n'`. You assign the result of the comparison to `ch`, but you want to assign the character.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((ch =getchar() != '\n') && x<MAX)
```

should be

```
while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && x<MAX)
```

Notice the extra `( .. )` around the assignment. `ch =getchar() != '\n'` is equivalent to and evaluated as `ch = (getchar() != '\n')` due to operator precedence. `!=` has higher precedence than `=`(assignment).